# Ajax load div of one page called from another page

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, load

I am facing with some glitches regarding the ajax load

OK, so the query is lets say I have page a (picture attached)
[image]

the ajax loads the div into the "RESULT" div on clicking the specific id's 
here is the ajax script & the html i have come so far. this loads perfectly on the Result div on the page a itself.

```
<a href="#" id="one" /><br>
<a href="#" id="two" /><br>
<a href="#" id="three" /><br>
<div id="result"  class="functions"></div>
```

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";


    var loadUrl = "content.php";
    $("#one").click(function () {
    $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
    });

    var load2Url = "content1.php";
    $("#two").click(function () {
    $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
    });

    var load3Url = "content2.php";
    $("#three").click(function () {
        $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(load2Url);
    });
```

thing is i need to load the same contents on the result div on page b from another page using the same id calls, lets say page b. 
[image]

the concept is, on page b, the id is clicked, it LOADS page a  first & loads the content on "RESULT" div. both pages are on the same server 
Would really appreciate any assistance. thank you.

Comment: are you using any server side technologies

Comment: no...nothing other than the ajax code here.
the pages are hosted on the same server. thats all.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle it will be to pass the dynamic item as a request parameter like in page b use the url `/pagea.html?section=one` etc

Then on page load

```
$(function(){
    var location = window.location.href;
    var page = location.substring(location.indexOf('=') + 1);
    $('#' + page).trigger('click');
})
```

Comment: I didnt quite catch your concept....
How do I specify which content to call on page a on click of an id on page b as there are more than one content aite.

Answer (score 0):

You got your `loadUrl`'s in the wrong pace they should be inside of the function otherwise it's value is the last value it was set to which is `content2.php`

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Class/HnH9S/1/)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});

var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";

$("#one").click(function () {
    var loadUrl = "content.php";
    $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
});

$("#two").click(function () {
    var loadUrl = "content1.php";
    $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
});

$("#three").click(function () {
    var loadUrl = "content2.php";
    $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the code. actually yep, the content does load by the ajax call on the page itself but i need to call the load function from another page...like i mentioned, on page b, one link with id=one is clicked, it loads page b & loads the content linked with id=one in the RESULT div. Is there a way to work around with it.